# How do you update the DOM during a function call in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a function call that takes about 15 seconds to execute. I am trying to show a loading spinner during this call. My understanding is the DOM will not update until the function completes unless I tell it to. I have tried `nextTick` and `async/await` but the spinner does not show until the function has completed. I have purposely left off `loading.value = false` at the end to show if the spinner is working just not showing until the function completes.

This is my UI

```
<template>
  <Background>
    <Card>
      <CardHeader
        title="Materials"
        description="All Current Materials"
        add-button-text="Add Materials"
        add-button-link="/settings/Materials/addMaterial"
      >
      </CardHeader>
      <div v-if="loading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ProgressSpinner />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button @click="add">Add</button>
    </Card>
  </Background>
</template>
```

Here is the code

```
<script setup>
const loading = ref(false);

let femaleStripSpacersNeeded = [];
let spacers = [];
let spacerQty = [];

const getSpacerAlgo = SpacerAlgo();

function add() {
  loading.value = true;
  let stripWidths = [3000, 21000, 3000];
  let stripTotal = [1, 1, 1];

  for (let z = 0; z < stripWidths.length; z++) {
    for (let n = 0; n < stripTotal[z]; n++) {
      let stripWidth = stripWidths[z];
      let femaleStripSpacers = getSpacerAlgo.minSpacers(
        stripWidth,
        spacers,
        spacerQty
      );
      femaleStripSpacersNeeded.push(femaleStripSpacers[0]);
      spacerQty = femaleStripSpacers[1];
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**
Added the `async/await` version I tried.

```
function add() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let stripWidths = [3000, 21000, 3000];
      let stripTotal = [1, 1, 1];

      for (let z = 0; z < stripWidths.length; z++) {
        for (let n = 0; n < stripTotal[z]; n++) {
          let stripWidth = stripWidths[z];
          let femaleStripSpacers = getSpacerAlgo.minSpacers(
            stripWidth,
            spacers,
            spacerQty
          );
          femaleStripSpacersNeeded.push(femaleStripSpacers[0]);
          spacerQty = femaleStripSpacers[1];
        }
      }
      resolve("resolved");
    });
  }

async function asyncCall() {
  loading.value = true;
  await add();
  loading.value = false;
}
```

Comment: the DOM updates as soon as any state used in the DOM is updated.  Once `loading.value = true` executes, the DOM will update `<div v-if="loading">` to true.  You haven't shown the template code for `<ProgressSpinner />` so it's not clear what if anything should actually appear in the DOM when this element is rendered, but if you inspect the DOM you should at least see the surrounding divs rendered by the v-if

Comment: If your code is doing asynchronous work (like HTTP requests), then the browser would be able to update the DOM according to already-completed changes. If there's *no* asynchronous stuff, well, 15 seconds on a modern computer is an insanely huge amount of work, and some algorithmic improvements could possibly improve that dramatically.

Comment: @yoduh The `<ProgressSpinner />` is PrimeVue's spinner. I know the spinner is working as I see it once the function completes. When I inspect the DOM nothing is rendered until the function completes

Comment: " I have tried nextTick and async/await" - what exactly did you try? This is the way to go. But generally you should have avoided blocking main thread and do expensive actions asynchronously

Comment: @EstusFlask I have made edits to the question to show my `async/await` version.

Comment: See this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fdlyog?file=src%2FApp.vue) which demonstrates that the async/await strategy with PrimeVue spinner works just fine. 
 The only difference is I have no idea what `SpacerAlgo()` is or where it comes from so I only mock an async operation instead of using your "SpacerAlgo" related code. I believe your problem is with the code inside the Promise, not with the Promise itself or with awaiting it.

Comment: @yoduh you are correct, if I put the `SpacerAlgo()` inside of the `timeout` function, the spinner shows for the timeout time then freezes once the `SpacerAlgo()` starts. I am going to move the `SpacerAlgo()` into a firebase cloud function which would solve my issue. Thank you

Comment: Should be `loading.value = true; await nextTick()`, that's the purpose that it serves

Comment: I bet this has nothing to do with async for sure the main thread is being blocked. if it really takes 15s then you should use webworker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has actually not much to do with Vue but more with the workload done by your `add()` function: everything in that function is called synchronously*; so if you say it *takes about 15 seconds to execute* that means it is *blocking* the [main thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread).
While the main thread is blocked by your function no other JavaScript can execute on that page.

* wrapping the `for` loops in a `Promise` doesn't change this. The code may then be *called* asychroniously but the computation in the `for` loops is still done in a single synchronous block as a whole.

The best way to solve your issue depends on your exact requirements. One way would be to move each call to `getSpacerAlgo.minSpacers()` **separately** on the message queue. This would then block the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop) only for a single call to `getSpacerAlgo.minSpacers()` at a time, allowing it to process other JavaScript code in between.

Another way could be using the [web worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) to move the calculations of `getSpacerAlgo.minSpacers()` completely off of the main thread. (Which is comparable to using a Firebase Cloud function only that the computation is still done in the browser).

If you want to learn more about the event loop have a look at this talk: [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: The web worker API was exactly what I needed. Greatly appreciate the help